# How do I move logic that generates HTML content in a foreach loop, to a pre-processing function?

Tags: 7, theming

On a module's .tpl file I have the following logic:

```
  <?php foreach ($element['store']['openingHours']['openingDays'] as $day_key => $opening_day):
   $i++;
   $i = ($i === 7 ? 0 : $i);
   if ($dayofweek == $i):
   if (empty($element['store']['openingHours'][$day_key . 'Open'])): ?>
   <p class="fcl-stores-hours__closed-today">
      Closed today
   </p>
   <?php else: ?>
   <p class="fcl-stores-hours__open-today">
     Open today until <?php print $element['store']['openingHours'][$day_key . 'Close']; ?>
   </p>
   <?php
    endif;        
    endif;
    endforeach; ?>
```

The code simply gets the current day-of-the-week from the server and loops through an array of the the store's opening days, then just prints either 'Closed today' or 'Open today'.

I've been told this should be here and that I need to move this logic to a preprocess function on my theme's template.php

But I'm unsure as to how to get the data back to the .tpl file where I can then apply it to the HTML.

Sorry if it's a broad question, but would any know what I should be doing here?

Comment: It's not like there's business logic there, some core templates have more advanced logic in them than that if memory serves. What justification did whoever told you it needs to be changed give, out of interest? You could arguably clean it up by setting up and passing through an array of class name and paragraph text in the preprocess function, but there's very little benefit in terms of "good practice"

Comment: @Clive I think their logic was that we could have that information saved to the array and thus available anywhere, even globally. Eg: just use something like `print $element['OpenDay'];` instead of re-writing the above each time it might be needed.